# zsh: command not found: service

Tags: macos, command, zsh

when i run the command

```
service mysql restart
```

following with the message like

```
zsh: command not found: service
```

and I can`t figure how to solve this problem.

I read an article which recommends me to change the PATH variable.

```
1 # If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
2 export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
3
4 # Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
5 export ZSH=/Users/jameskoo/.oh-my-zsh
```

Above is what my ~/.zshrc file looks like.

Since I`m new to mac and also with zsh.

I clearly don`t know how to set up the PATH variable.

I`m searching for solutions for hours but having difficulties

I want to know how to setup the PATH variable.

Any recommendations would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

You could add your service like this:

```
export NAME=/path/to/your/service
```

and then, in the .zshrc file, in the line

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

add your NAME to the path like this:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$NAME:$PATH
```

Save it and then read the source with:

```
> source ~/.zshrc
```

And you're good to go. Hope it helps.